# set the dialog modal width for jquery ui?

Tags: jquery-ui

HI

I am using [this demo](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) to display a modal dialog

how do I set the width for dialog if i am using it for google street view:

```
var point = new GLatLng(svlat, svlon);
var panoClient = new GStreetviewClient(); 
panoClient.getNearestPanoramaLatLng(point, function (newPoint) {
  if (newPoint == null) {
      alert("no panorama found for this position!!");
      return;
  }
  panoramaOptions = { latlng: newPoint };
  myPano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
  $('#dialogStreetView').dialog("option", "maxWidth", 600);
  $('#dialogStreetView').dialog('open');
  GEvent.addListener(myPano, "error", handleNoFlash);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialogStreetView" title="Street View Provided by Google... "     style="width:300px;height:300px">
    <a id="closestreet-view" name="closestreet-view" style="cursor:pointer; text-   decoration:underline" >Close</a>
    <div name="pano" id="pano" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the docs:

- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

this should work:

```
$("#dialogStreetView").dialog( "option", "width", 460 );
```

Comment: I tried this $('#dialogStreetView').dialog("option", "maxWidth", 600);, it is only width,I need a coffee,

Comment: Well, there's actually a `maxWidth` as a separate option. Check the docs, and yes a coffee works wery well :)

Comment: And if you want to do this when the dialog opens, make sure you attach the above to the create event, not the open event.

Comment: Worked like charm. +1

Answer (score 20):

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#myDialogBox" ).dialog({
  width: 500,
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  }
}); 
$( "#myBoxOpener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#myDialogBox" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>
```

====== body ======

```
<div id="myDialogBox" title="My Dialog Box">
    <div id="myContentLayer">
    <p>My Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="myBoxOpener" class="myButton">Open Dialog Box</button>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/portashqipe/shsgjpgh/)

Answer (score 5):

Is it just me does everyone except Porta have a syntax error:

```
$( "#selector" ).dialog( {
  width: 500
} );
```

took from http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width

Answer (score 3):

simply just add width:500

```
$('#dialogStreetView').dialog( width: 500,"option", "maxWidth", 600);
```